# App Studio is auto-converting my app to Schema 1.9, and the failing to install it into Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm uploading an app manifest into App Studio that's an older version (happens to be 1.5), but when I try Install it using App Studio, it fails. When I go to the schema editor inside App Studio, it shows me it's changed it to Schema Version 1.9, which I think is the issue.

Incidentally, this user is having a similar-but-different issue: [App Studio is generating a version 1.9 manifest which fails validation and stops side loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66120464/app-studio-is-generating-a-version-1-9-manifest-which-fails-validation-and-stops) earlier today.

Answer (score 1):

We are able to repro the issue. Raised a bug. We don't have ETA to share when it will be fixed.
Please follow this [Git-hub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/2765) for updates on bug.

Comment: Great, thanks for update. I've side-loaded to store in the meantime, but wanted to report it so it can get addressed.

Comment: Bug is Resolved now, we have tested this at our end, could you please also check and confirm?
The issue is with the Teams client which is fixed now.

Comment: yup, looks better