# Microrosft teams Usupported Manifest Version

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, manifest, microsoft-teams, custom-application

I'm developing a custom teams app and until few days ago it was running ok: wep app run local from visual studio code with chrome debug, and the service app distributed on azure.

Yesterday I deleted by mistake the local app from app studio (inside visual studio code) and then I created a new app and set it as the old.

Teams recognize the app and when I run it from local (with debug from chrome) it opens a new window on chrome and I correctly see the button for install it: [image]

When I click install I receive one popUp error: [image] and i can see thi erro on the local visual studio debug console: [image]

My manifest app is a standard manifest, with 1.8 version:

```
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.8/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.8",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "d8bf27a8-a5a3-4381-9dd8-696d473450a1",
  "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.eclexia",
  "developer": {
    "name": "",
    "websiteUrl": "https://localhost:3000",
    "privacyUrl": "https://localhost:3000/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://localhost:3000/termsofuse"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "",
    "full": ""
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "",
    "full": ""
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "index",
      "name": "Catalogo",
      "contentUrl": "https://localhost:3000/tab?tid={tid}&aaId={userObjectId}",
      "websiteUrl": "https://localhost:3000/tab",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    },
    {
      "entityId": "live",
      "name": "Live",
      "contentUrl": "https://localhost:3000/live?tid={tid}&aaId={userObjectId}",
      "websiteUrl": "https://localhost:3000/live",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "searchQuery",
          "type": "query",
          "title": "Search",
          "description": "Test command to run query",
          "initialRun": false,
          "fetchTask": false,
          "context": [
            "compose",
            "commandBox"
          ],
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "searchQuery",
              "title": "Search Query",
              "description": "Your search query",
              "inputType": "text"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "localhost"
  ]
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently a bug with App Studio that's being addressed (see my question here: [App Studio is auto-converting my app to Schema 1.9, and the failing to install it into Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66121113/app-studio-is-auto-converting-my-app-to-schema-1-9-and-the-failing-to-install-i)). In the meantime, you can side-load to the internal company app store, and install from there, especially if you have a Developer tenant